# What is the purpose of NSWindow's orderOut/Back/Front's sender argument?

Tags: macos, cocoa

This question is regarding the following member functions of NSWindow in the Cocoa framework:

```
func orderOut(_ sender: AnyObject?)
func orderBack(_ sender: AnyObject?)
func orderFront(_ sender: AnyObject?)
func makeKeyAndOrderFront(_ sender: AnyObject?)
```

There are no comments in the OS X 10.11.4 documentation regarding the purpose or effect of the sender argument, and I am curious as to how they affect the behavior of the functions.

Comment: It does just [what the documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419204-orderback?language=objc) ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the point you're trying to get at. I've read that page, and each of the pages for the functions I've listed. All they say is that the sender is the message originator. I get that. What it doesn't say--what all of the pages don't say--is how this argument affects the behavior of the function. A function doesn't just have an argument for no reason. Why is it there? I still have a very valid question.

Comment: vadian's answer is correct. You may also want to read [“Target-Action” in *Cocoa Application Competencies for OS X*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Devpedia-CocoaApp-MOSX/TargetAction.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sender` argument is for convenience to use the methods as `IBAction` for menu items or other UI elements.